# Built-In PowerShell Module Path

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure out where the built-in modules are hosted in the filesystem. I would've thought it an easy task, but I'm not having much luck. Most/all of the Google results are about getting the path of the current script or adding a search-path. I'm searching the hard drive for the nouns in the names and have not been successful. I've searched for general "ps1" files, in general, and haven't been successful. I've searched both "Program Files" directories and the "Windows" directory as well.

I'm using the ISE to find scripts whose nouns I can search for, but the built-in ones seem uselessly-generically named (too many results) and the proprietary ones are probably located somewhere non-general (as I understand that there's a search-path that might've been updated by the install-process).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did you forget to use google? ;-)

Comment: @Colyn1337 Have you? Most/all of the results are about getting the path of the current script or adding a search-path.

Comment: Actually yes, it's how I found the answer to this question when I needed to know years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a specific user(s):

```
%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Module
```

For all users on the computer:

```
%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
```

Documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350(v=vs.85).aspx) in the MSDN document.

Comment: Also, C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules (for reference, this is a PS 4.0 system).

Comment: is this really correct? `get-module | select path` gives me other paths, especially for the Built-In modules which the OP asked for. as he said correctly they are in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`and some are in `C:\program files\windowsPowerShell\modules`. Why does the command give me other results, is the command not correct for this task?